# Force chunked transfers when using gzip static on / sendfile in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, chunked

Nginx seems to disable chunking when sending files that are pre-compressed ala `gzip_static on`

Is there any trick to force it to chunk anyway? Chunks seems to give some browsers the illusion of faster rendering because they might use the chunk point as a render refresh point.

HTTP/1.1 should allow any file to be sent chunked, static or not.

Or perhaps this is a limitation with sendfile OS acceleration?

Comment: `Chunks seems to give some browsers the illusion of faster rendering because they might use the chunk point as a render refresh point.` Any reference to illustrate this statement?

Comment: facebook is a perfect example of that, i know this post is old but im looking for the awnser to this question also

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the way `sendfile()` works:

> Note, however, that because the data never touches user space it’s not subject to the filters in the regular NGINX processing chain. As a result, filters that change content, for example the gzip filter, have no effect.

https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/